# Is there a better way to implement single source of truth with rxjava in android

Tags: android, rx-java2

In my app I have database which uses Room and a network service using retrofit. I have a requirement where if there is no data in local database I need to query the network and show a progress bar. If the network returns empty data then I need to show a empty view. One of the problem is that I need to ignore the empty data from the room and only consider empty data from the server so that when the user doesn't have any data he just sees a loading view and after the server returns empty data he will see empty view.

I have implemented this using a publish subject. Lce(loading content error) is wrapper object around data.

```
val recentPublish = PublishSubject.create<Lce<List<RecentMessage>>>()

fun loadRecentMessages() {
        loadMessageFromDB()
        loadRecentMessageFromServer()
}
private fun loadMessageFromDB() {
    disposable = recentMessageDao.getRecentMessages() // this is a flowable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe({
            Timber.d("recent message from db size ${it.size}")
            handleMessageFromDB(it)
        }, {
            it.printStackTrace()
            Timber.e("error on flowable from db!")
        })
}
protected fun handleMessageFromDB(messages: List<RecentMessage>) {
    // only publish if the data is not empty
    if (messages.isNotEmpty()) {
        recentPublish.onNext(Lce.Content(messages))
    }
}

private fun loadRecentMessageFromServer() {
    recentPublish.onNext(Lce.Loading())
    networkService.getLatestMessage() // this is a single
        .subscribe({
            val parsedMessages =
                DtoConverter.convertRecentPrivateMessageResponse(it, user.id!!)
            handleMessageFromServer(parsedMessages)
        }, {
            it.printStackTrace()
            recentPublish.onNext(Lce.Error(it))
            Timber.w("failed to load recent message for private chat from server")
        })
}

private fun handleMessageFromServer(recentMessages: List<RecentMessage>) {
    Timber.i("recent messages from server ${recentMessages.size}")
    if (recentMessages.isEmpty()) {
        recentPublish.onNext(Lce.Content(arrayListOf()))
    } else {
        recentMessageDao.saveAll(recentMessages)
    }
}
```

In the above code I am only passing the empty data from server and ignoring the empty data from room. This solution works but I wonder if there is some better functional approach to solve this problem. I am a beginner to Rxjava and any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are using multiple independent subscriptions for something that should be sequential and this can cause race conditions, consider the use of `flatMap {` operator. You could even `flatMap {` the network request and then `map` that response + previous DB data into a `Pair`.

Comment: Thank you for your response @EpicPandaForce , I am a beginner to rxjava so I have a hard time figuring out how to do that. If you have any time, could you please provide some codes to help me out.

Comment: `flatMap` like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717323/2413303

Comment: Thank you @EpicPandaForce I think I have figured it. I have posted my answer, I think it is fine.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you please tell how i can achieve this scenario with Live Data ?

Comment: switchMap......

Answer (score 1):

After some research and the comment from @EpicPandaForce, I came up with this approach. I learned quite few things and it just clicked on me, about how to correctly use rxjava. Here is my approach, any comment will be appreciated.

```
    fun getMessages(): Observable<Lce<List<RecentMessage>>> {
        return Observable.mergeDelayError(getMessagesFromDB(), getMessagesFromNetwork()) // even if network fails, we still want to observe the DB
    }

    private fun getMessagesFromDB(): Observable<Lce.Content<List<RecentMessage>>> {
        return recentMessageDao.getRecentMessages()
            .filter {
                it.isNotEmpty() // only forward the data from db if it's not empty
            }.map {
                Lce.Content(it)
            }
    }

    private fun getMessagesFromNetwork(): Observable<Lce<List<RecentMessage>>> {
        // first show a loading , then request for data
        return Observable.concat(Observable.just(Lce.Loading()), profileService.getLatestMessage()
                .flatMap {
                    processServerResponse(it) // store the data to db
                }.onErrorReturn {
                    Lce.Error(it)
                }.filter {
                    (it as Lce.Content).packet.isEmpty() // only forward data if it's empty
                })
    }


    private fun processServerResponse(response: RecentMessageResponse): Observable<Lce<List<RecentMessage>>> {
        return Observable.create {
            val parsedMessages =
                DtoConverter.convertRecentPrivateMessageResponse(response, user.id!!)
            handleMessageFromServer(parsedMessages)
            it.onComplete() // we use single source of truth so don't return anyting
        }
    }
```

Comment: susan Thapa can you please tell how i can acheive this scenario with LiveData ?